# Catching errors inside window.onerror?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've setup a `window.onerror` handler to catch errors. Its purpose? To concat a string for each time an error occurs, then another handler `window.onunload` sends it off to the Server. (Presumably with all the errors).

Problem is, it's only able to send the first error over, because after the `onerror` handler event fires for the first time, the error isn't caught and thus the script terminates...

Is there a way around this?

```
ErrorManager: (function () {
        function Init(message) {
            InitErrorHandler();
            InitAjaxHandler();
            setTimeout("Interface.ErrorManager.SendErrorsToAjax()", 8000);
        }
        function InitErrorHandler() {
            Data.ErrorHandlerText = "";
            Data.ErrorHandlerCount = 0;
            window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
                if(IsInIgnoreList(errorMessage)) { return; }
                Data.ErrorHandlerText += ("Error: "+(Data.ErrorHandlerCount+1)+" <br /><br />");
                //Get error specific info
                Data.ErrorHandlerText += escape(errorMessage) + "<br />";
                Data.ErrorHandlerText +=  escape(url) + "<br />";
                Data.ErrorHandlerText +=  escape(line) + "<br />";
                Data.ErrorHandlerCount++;
                console.log("BOOM"+errorMessage);
            }
        }

        function InitAjaxHandler() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function() { //when browser closed
                Data.ErrorHandlerCount > 0 && SendErrorsToAjax();
            }
        }
        function SendErrorsToAjax() {
            PrepareErrorsForAjax();
            $.getJSON(Interface.Utility.PrefixURL('/ajax/sendfeedback/handlejserrors/'+Data.ErrorHandlerText));
        }
        function IsInIgnoreList(str) {
            return str.indexOf('nsIDOMSVGLocatable') != -1 ? true : false;
        }

        function PrepareErrorsForAjax() {
            var preText = "<br /><br />A user has encountered a few errors: <br /><br />";
            //Get session info
            var userAgent, activePageID, accountNO, consumerNO;
            userAgent = escape(navigator.userAgent);
            preText += "User agent: "+userAgent+" <br />";

            if($.mobile.activePage) {
                activePageID = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
                preText += "Page ID: "+activePageID+" <br />";
            }
            //Get info that may or may not be set
            console.log("AUTH JSON "+Data.authJSON);
            console.log("CONSUMER JSON "+Data.authJSON.consumers);
            if(Data.authJSON && localStorage.lastConsumerNo) {
                preText += "Account Number: " +Data.authJSON.accountId+" <br />";
                preText += "Consumer Number: "+ localStorage.lastConsumerNo+" <br />";
            }
            preText += "<br /> The following errors were encountered:<br /><br />";
            Data.ErrorHandlerText = preText + Data.ErrorHandlerText;
        }
        return {
            Init: Init,
            SendErrorsToAjax: SendErrorsToAjax
        }
    })(),
```

Comment: Please attach some code.

Comment: Say it again sam, that was the first thing i thought about, Yes, use try/catch blocks.

Comment: Try and catch only works for a certain section. I want it for all errors, you can create a stupid pass through function but don't want to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add it in a seperate `<script>` tag, so that `window.onerror` is not bothered by script errors in other script tags.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ebgv7/)

```
<script>
    var trackErrorMsg = '';
    window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo)  {
      trackErrorMsg += msg;     
    }
</script>
```

Please Note the above doesn't stop error being logged in the browser console.. The above code is just to track the errors.. You should use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to handle errors in any specific sections.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ebgv7/1/) - To show that it **doesn't work** when you have it on the same execution context.

Comment: That's not actually working, (unexpectedly), it's still only handling one error. Have whipped it in another script tag before the new one.

Comment: Infact... doesn't it make sense that it only fires once? If multiple errors occurs in my script block with actual logic, then THAT script gets exited, but my handler script block doesn't. but because the other one was exited, its not going to catch anymore. So the limit is one error per block?

Comment: After a js error, your browser will stop executing any following lines in the script(inside the same <script></script> block) and will proceed to next <script> block. That is why it will be executed only once when you have the 'window.onerror' on the same <script> block. Please try the DEMO links which will give you an idea of what I am talking about.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz - What doesn't work? Please be more descriptive on what is not working?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the demo doesn't work. But What I said before is, once a single script block has hit an error, you can't log anymore errors from that script block. So its 1 max per script block, unless you start catching errors but that means you've gotta whip it inside every function.

Comment: Why would you think that adding a second script block would do anything (which it doesn't). For any given web page, there is one DOM and one single-threaded execution context stack. Breaking code into multiple script blocks does not affect the single execution context stack.

Comment: @user1739635 When a script error occurs inside a script block, the following code after the error **in that block** will not be executed and the browser would proceed to the next script block. This is the reason the above answer wraps the `onerror` in a separate script block.

Comment: @user1739635 Seems like I have explained it earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491301/catching-errors-inside-window-onerror/9491375#comment12016045_9491375

Comment: Do you really believe that breaking code into multiple scripts is a viable solution for any production code?  Since runtime errors, by their very nature, aren't predictable, how is one to know which code to isolate into a second script block. Your advice is foolhardy and not recommended in any production environment.

Comment: @user1739635 You don't need to isolate any "unpredictable" code. Everything can stay the same, just the `window.onerror` code should be in a separate script block. Did you try out the demo?

Comment: @Vega  I don't think you understand. if I setup an onerror handling function in one script and then an error occurs in another script, the code in the second script will stop executing.  It will not continue beyond the error. You have continuously asked myself and others if we've tried your demo and the answer is that your demo doesn't work (as many have said).

Comment: @user1739635 I am confused now, The question is

Comment: @Vega The fact is that when an error occurs (even with an error handler in a different script tag), after the onerror handler does its thing, no further code in the original script block will run. Yes, code execution will continue into any additional script blocks that may follow, but as I said, this is not a viable solution, because you wouldn't necessarily know where your run-time errors are, and so, you wouldn't know what code to break into additional script blocks.to ensure they get processed.  The only real way to use onerror reliably is when using only callback code (continued)...

Comment: @Vega ... because if one callback fails, the onerror will kick in, but additional callbacks that are triggered later will still execute.  It is only the current Execution Context that stops processing when an error is encountered. Since each callback is its own function, it will run within its own Execution Context. Essentially, onerror should not be relied on for code running in the Global Execution Context.